# syncdb not happening using south for migration

Tags: django, migration, django-south, syncdb

```
Synced:
 > django.contrib.auth
 > django.contrib.contenttypes
 > django.contrib.sessions
 > django.contrib.sites
 > django.contrib.messages
 > django.contrib.staticfiles
 > django.contrib.admin
 > django.contrib.admindocs
 > kaarya.account
 > kaarya.project
 > south

Not synced (use migrations):
 - kaarya.inspector
(use ./manage.py migrate to migrate these)
Finished "C:\Documents and Settings\EC.32-SAMUEL\workspace\kaarya\kaarya\manage.py syncdb" execution.
```

I once installed south and tried implementing migration then also prompted as Not synced (use migrations ):

Note : Here kaarya is my project and inspector is the app i tried migrating once using south but was not successful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try

```
python manage.py migrate
```

If so what was the error?

Comment: Am using south on my existing project . I have converted my app inspector for migration using manage.py convert_to_south inspector